# acceptable MVC parameter usage

Tags: model-view-controller

would it be considered a valid implementation if I do not use the model for certain parameters? For example a webform posting values directly to the controller which then passes them to another class. Is it necessary to make sure that all the fields in the webform are also referenced/stored in the model?

Comment: There's no requirement in MVC that every field in the webform have a corresponding field in the model.  Quite the contrary; there are ViewModel objects that act as a go-between, and they don't necessarily map one-to-one with either the Model or the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider it a valid implementation, but suggest that you do this only if the parameters you want to exclude from the Model are absolutely NOT going to be used by the View (other than for confirmation of data entry in your webform), AND there is no need for the parameters to be referenced again once handled by the Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would work, strictly speaking.

However, you probably want to use the model.  You don't want to create a new variable every time you run the view, which would happen if you use the controller.

Comment: My specific example would be having a form post method containing: MethodForWhatever("Request.From[fromfield]"]). Instead of the having my view reference the model with <input name="model.field" /> and MethodForWhatever(model.field) in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it valid implementation if you decided not to use the model for certain parameters. I believe there are instances where certain fields may not relate directly to the model in question therefore giving valid reason to break those fields/parameters off from the model.

Comment: It depends what you consider to be a "Model". If that is a DB-related class, then sure. But in classical MVC understanding model is just a class representing data in the view. And Model in a view does not always match your Model in a DB.